# Create a procedure named 'select_city'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Create a procedure named 'select_city' which accepts one input parameter user_id of type number and one output parameter city_details of type varchar. This procedure is used to display the city_details of user.If the user is from bangalore then display the city_details as 'User is from Bangalore',or if the user is from chennai then display the city_details as 'User is from Chennai', else display the city_details as 'User is from other cities'.
'''

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SELECT_CITY(user_id IN number,city_details OUT number)
u_city varchar2(255);
begin
select city into u_city from contact where id=user_id;
if(u_city='bangalore') then
city_details:='User is from Bangalore';
elseif u_city='chennai' then
city_details:='User is from Chennai';
else
city_details:='User is from other cities';
end if;
end;
/
```

'''

Comment: Just to comment on the code, it's `if condition then`, not `if (condition) then`. You can add brackets but they are unnecessary and the compiler ignores them.

Comment: Also, in this type of tutorial example, 'display' usually seems to mean `dbms_output.put_line`, a debugging procedure generally avoided in real-life production code but useful in simple examples. So maybe you just need to construct a message that includes whatever city is returned from the CONTACT table, like `'User is from '||u_city`

Answer (score 2):

As it is a stored procedure that returns a value, you'll have yet another PL/SQL block (of some kind) to make it work. Here's an example.

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from contact;

   USER_ID CITY
---------- ---------
         1 Bangalore
         2 Zagreb

SQL>
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure select_city
  2    (par_user_id in number, par_city_details out varchar2)
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    select 'User is from ' ||
  6        case when city in ('Bangalore', 'Chennai') then city
  7             else 'other city'
  8        end
  9      into par_city_details
 10      from contact
 11      where user_id = par_user_id;
 12  end;
 13  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_msg varchar2(100);
  3  begin
  4    select_city(1, l_msg);
  5    dbms_output.put_line(l_msg);
  6  end;
  7  /
User is from Bangalore

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
    
SQL>   l4
  4*   select_city(1, l_msg);
SQL> c/1/2
  4*   select_city(2, l_msg);
SQL> /
User is from other city

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```